# assembly convert from hex to base 3

Tags: assembly

I want to convert number from hex (base 16) to ternary (base 3),
a simple solution is to convert each digit like so hex->decimal->binary->ternary,
is there more efficient(=meaning less code) for this problem?

Comment: Hex->binary is very simple (it's a no-op unless your hex value is a string, but even then it's pretty simple). So do hex->binary->ternary.

Comment: @PaulR it is a string, can you explain the process ?

Comment: Each hex character maps directly to 4 binary bits. 0 -> 0000, 1 -> 0001, ..., 9 -> 1001, A -> 1010, ..., F -> 1111. So if your string is 137f then this becomes 0001 0011 0111 1111. Maybe do it in an HLL first (e.g. C) to get the logic right, then convert this to asm ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what do you mean by "binary". If you mean - CPU's internal representation, that's definitely the way to go. Converting a number to a string in any numeric system involves integer arithmetic, and doing that with a string representation of a number is cumbersome.

If you mean - binary string, a string with characters "0" and "1", you couldn't be more wrong.

Anyway, the proper algorithm would involve:

- converting a number from a hex string to an integer (if it's a compile-time constant - the assembler will)
- dividing said integer by three in a loop, until you reach zero
- storing the remainder of each division - that's your ternary digit
- converting ternary digits to ASCII
- outputting

Answer (score 1):

To convert a number in base m into a number in base n:

- convert the original base m number into an integer. This is easy (it's mostly a "value = value + digit * base" loop).
- convert that integer into base n.  This is easy (it's mostly a "digit = value % base; value = value / base" loop).

For some cases (e.g. converting between hex and integers) it's easy to optimise the calculation by using shifts and masks instead of multiplication, division and modulo.